Why can't I make a REST connection to Oracle document understanding
I am trying to make a REST data source to Oracle document understanding in my Oracle Apex application. But I get an error:

ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

REST data source creation
Error message
I followed the exact lab provided by Oracle itself and yet they have not mentioned any reference on this specific error

If the problem is not the URL, then the object not found may be the bucket you should have created at Task 2 of Lab 1.

This error was triggered because the specific service was not available in the mentioned region. It worked when i used another region

interesting…  it's in the list https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/document-understanding/20221109/, maybe a temp problem…

@p3consulting yes it's temporary issue from there side.
